# Binding the Json response to Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I am bit confuse how to bind the response in my kendo grid.

Getting the response form service like below

[image]

I need to show the response in Grid as shown below

[image]

i am using angular js, MVC and kendo for Grids.

which is the best to modify my response data to in Grid. In MVC or Angular js.

thanks advance

Comment: Kendo grid has a feature of grouping rows by keys. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can’t do it native in grid. But you can use workaround - change you data to represent necessary view.

I modified someone’s fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SugMK/47/

**First** you must group you data, in you example `uid` determines `id` and `title`, so you can group it on `uid`:

```
var result = _.groupBy(result, (item) => { return item.uid });
```

**Second** Iterate in resulted object which have structure like

```
{ 
   uid1:  [
           {row1_with_uid1}, 
           {row2_with_uid1}
          ], 
    uid2: [
           {row1_with_uid2}, 
           {row2_with_uid2}
          ] 
}
```

And aggregate (or not) necessary rows with you custom logic. In your case you must combine two `code` fields as text with `br` as separator:

```
_.forEach(result, (items) => {
     var newItem = items[0]; // set default.

     items.splice(0, 1); // since first item is default - remove it from aggregate array
     _.forEach(items, (item) => { newItem.code = newItem.code + "<br />" + item.code; }); // aggregate item.

     newResult.push(newItem); // save aggregated item.
});
```

**Third** You must set `encoded` parameter of aggregated field (code) to `false`, for representing your `br`'s as HTML, not text:

```
{ field: "code", title: "multiline", encoded: false }
```

P.S. I think you can create your own much better realization but I create this example for better understanding my idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer letting the grid's data source handle data grouping and aggregation then simply use the grid's data source. The code below is razor syntax, however, there is a direct equivalent in Kendo ui js.

```
DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Server()
    .Aggregates(aggregates =>
    {
        aggregates.Add(p => p.Amount).Sum();
    })
    .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.CustomerName)
)
```